# Using web.config on a sub-level to redirect users

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config, iis-7.5

The application currently has a web.config file at root level and this is shared between all customers. This web config file has the redirects for all customers and every time we modify this web.config for 1 customer, we are putting all other customers at risk.

Each customer has a folder named after them, which is where their theme files and customisations are stored. This location is the ideal place for a web.config file that contains redirects for just that single customer, which can be modified at anytime without putting others at risk.

My current attempts at putting a web.config file at the lowest level looks like it's being read by the server but it fails for some reason. The web config file is very small and only contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions>
          <remove fileExtension="."/>
          <add fileExtension="." allowed="true"/>
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="test" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="www.example.com/old_website" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="www.example.com/new_website"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have my suspicions that it's simply not possible to have a web.config file at such a low level and expect it to work in the same way it does at root level. However, if it is possible and you have an idea for me to try, I would appreciate it.

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 0):

It's no problem solving the access the way you try to do it, just add an extra touch to it. :)

I don't know how you handle all the different users but I suppose you have some kind of log in function. When they log in just set some session cookies that you might need for future use. I have a similar solution and I set redirect as a session variable when they log in instead of in the web.config. Then in your subfolder you give only the user logged in access and deny all other users. This look something like this.

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="John"/>
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Here you allow John access to the folder and you deny access to everyone else.

When it comes to error handling I have this in my web.config in root.

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Error/Customerror.html"/>
</system.web>
```

The remote only give errors only on local computor (not on web server) and the default redirect handles any custom error that will arise, also when a user tries to get into a folder they don't have access to. This works like a charm and is tidy.